# show only results after todays date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with dates and information associated with it. The problem I am having is that I am trying to get it to show only results that match after a certain date.

The way I have tried is using MySQL, if it is possible I would like an answer in mysqli which is more protected.

```
include("connect.php");
$query=("SELECT * FROM availability WHERE day >= date('Y-m-d')");
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['day'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['hour'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['booked'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
```

Comment: What is `DATE('Y-m-d')` supposed to represent? That just returns `NULL`.

Comment: in his example im guess it should be the current date

Comment: Usually comparisons are like `day >= NOW()` or `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`.

Comment: [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and provides a lot of benefits `mysqli` doesn't. If you can, update to that instead.

Comment: im trying to show the date in the y-m-d format @tadman

Comment: That is not a format. Try: `SELECT DATE('Y-m-d')`. Then, like you should've done long ago, read the documentation on [how `DATE()` works](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date). The dates in MySQL are [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) by default: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. It's okay to ask questions, but when you're blatantly mis-using the function it's obvious you didn't check first.

Comment: thanks, all fixed thank you for all the help i will change it to PDO asap

Comment: Hope that works out for you. I think you'll find it's a lot more pleasant to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) **MySQL** function to get and compare the current date with column.

Use it like this,

```
$query=("SELECT * FROM availability WHERE day >= CURDATE()");
```

As @tadman suggested

> Do not use the mysql_query interface.
>  It’s so awful and dangerous that
>   it was removed in PHP 7. Instead, the **MySQLi** or **PDO_MySQL** extension should be used.